# Is there a possibility to customize the behavior of the buttons for ControlsFX wizard

Tags: java, wizard, controlsfx

[Current GUI with the buttons in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NROjm.png)

My problem is that I need to prevent the user from clicking the Next Button when specific conditions are not met, I thought the best way for this would be to overwrite the onClickEvent for this Button but it seems impossible to the required field access to these buttons.

I looked through the available methods in the documentation as well as the source code but I was not able to find anything which would help to achieve my goal.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The only solution I found was to basically copy the Wizard class(by this I mean to copy the src. code) change the necessary parts there